# Reactjs input value is not changing

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I have a reactjs form, on page load it will show all values from database which user can change and submit. When I am trying to change input value, it updates state but not UI.

Below is the sample code. My form has many input controls.

```
const [user, setUser] = useState({});
 
useEffect(() => {
  //calling api and update state on page load
  setUser(response);
}, [])
    
    
const handleChange= (e)=>{
  let track= user;
  track[e.target.name]=e.target.value;
  setUser(track);
}
  
//HTML CODE
<form name='NewUser'>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input
          className="form-control"
          name="firstInput"
          onChange={handleChange}
          type="number"
          min="0"
          max="1000"
          value={user.firstInput}
        />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input
          className="form-control"
          name="secondInput"
          onChange={handleChange}
          type="number"
          min="0"
          max="1000"
          value={user.secondInput}
        />
      </td>
    <tr/>
  </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mutating the state object! You are also not providing a new object reference for the React state. React is bailing out of rerenders since the state reference never updates.

```
const handleChange= (e) => {
  let track= user; // <-- track is reference to state
  track[e.target.name]=e.target.value; // <-- state mutation!
  setUser(track); // <-- save state reference back into state
}
```

You need to create a new state object, then update. Use a functional state update to access the previous user state and shallow copy it into a new object reference, and update the specified property by the dynamic key.

```
const handleChange= (e) => {
  setUser(user => ({
    ...user,
    [e.target.name]: e.target.value
  }));
}
```

Comment: Thank you Drew. If user is an array of object and need to update one property based on index, is is possible using above method?

Comment: @Anil It would be similar, but uses `Array.prototype.map` to shallow copy the array and uses the mapped index to then shallow copy the specific element you want to update. It'll look like this `setState(state => state.map((el, i) => i === index ? { ...el, [key]: value } : el))`.

Comment: @oykn Can't really say anything about that code without a more complete example. It's off-topic for this question it seems, but you are more than welcome to post a new question. Feel free to ping me here in a comment with a link to it if you do, and I can take a look when available.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72041289/how-can-i-see-data-from-data-in-state-in-react  @DrewReese thank you.