# How can I update the value from the database in React

Tags: reactjs, use-state

When I edit the form here, I need to show the value in the database. so how can i get this value

```
const dataValue = ndata.filter((obj) => obj._id === dataid ).map((aa)=> {
   return (
      {aa.AddressTitle}
   )
})
```

The datavalue comes in correctly but I can't show it as the default value in state why

```
const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    billingAddr: false,
    shippingAddr: false,
    AddressTitle: isEdit===true ? (dataValue):("")
  });
```

i should show this as default value in AddressTitle.

**UPDATE QUEST**

```
   useEffect(() => {
        const api = async () => {
            try {
              const response = await authService.getAddr();
              setndata(response?.data);
              response.data
                ?.filter((obj) => obj._id === dataid)
                .map((data) => setFormData({ ...formData, AddressTitle: data.AddressTitle }));
            } catch (error) {
              console.log(error);
            }
          };
          api();
    });   

  <TextField fullWidth id="outlined-basic" label="Address Title"  
       variant="outlined" size="small"
       value={formData.AddressTitle} 
       onChange={(e) => { setFormData(formData => ({ ...formData,  
       AddressTitle: e.target.value }));
        }} />
```

When I click edit, I see the correct value in the textfield, but I cannot change it. so I should be able to update the textfield I entered.Incoming data stays constant in the textfield, how can I update it?

Answer (score 1):

dataValue is an array.

try this and tell me

```
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
      billingAddr: false,
      shippingAddr: false,
      AddressTitle: isEdit===true ? yourDisplayFunction() :("")
    });
    
    const yourDisplayFunction = (dataValue) => {
      const dataValues = dataValue.map(value => {
        return <>dataValue.AdressTitle</>
      });
    
      return <>dataValues</>
    }
```

Comment: exactly when I call the function in this format (yourDisplayFunction(dataValue)) , return as [Object, Object].  
when i write this directly instead of dataValue   ` ndata.filter((obj) => obj._id === dataid ).map((aa)=> { return <>aa.AdressTitle</>
      });   `   don't you get the same?

Comment: ++ dataValue is an array. but I'm mapping and Only one value should be returned. <> {aa.AddressTitle}</>

Comment: give me the whole code im gonna try and tell you

Answer (score 0):

`dataValue` is an array of objects because `[x, y, z].map(item => {item})` returns `[ {x}, {y}, {z}]`

So you are expecting a `string` from an array of objects. ("a" is not equivalent to `dataValue`)

Comment: then how can i get string like?

Comment: why do you expect dataValue to be a string ?

Comment: couse I should get the value from data in state's value. like this defaultValue. 
when I edit the form, I should see the title of the one I am editing when it first opens

Comment: [more details my questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72055385/why-are-state-values-returning-undefined-with-reactjs/72055695#72055695)  @EEAH

Comment: when you set the state, why you expect that dataValue is a string when assigning it to AddressTitle ?

Comment: how can i get it i don't expect it to be a string.  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({ AddressTitle: ??  });  otherwise it returns empty. how can it be shown