# Why are state values ​returning undefined? with reactjs

Tags: reactjs, use-state

```
const [value, setValue]=useState();

 useEffect(() => {
    authService.getAddr().then((response) => {
      setndata(response.data);
    },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
   ndata.filter((obj) => obj._id === dataidM).map((data) => setValue(data.AddressTitle));
  }, [dataidM, ndata]);

  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    billingAddr: false,
    shippingAddr: false,
    AddressTitle:`Hello, ${value} !`   **// value is undefined**
  });

   return  (
   <div>  ......
     <div className='bg-info'>
       {dataidM} --- {ndata.filter((obj) => obj._id === dataidM).map((data) => { return 
       data.AddressTitle })} -- --{value} 
     </div>   **//I can see the values ​​as I want here when I check**
  </div>
)
```

Why is it returning undefined in the other place, how can I show this value there? By default it should appear.

Answer (score 2):

To connect the variables you need to add an effect like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
   setFormData({
    billingAddr: false,
    shippingAddr: false,
    AddressTitle:`Hello, ${value} !`
  });
}, [value]);
```

This way every time value changes formData will change with it.

*a good note is that it is not recommended to use variables like so and just use `Hello, ${value} !` in the rendering instead of a new variable.

More details as to why it was undefined:

```
const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    billingAddr: false,
    shippingAddr: false,
    AddressTitle:`Hello, ${value} !`   **// value is undefined**
  });
```

Here you set the default of the value and this default uses the default value, which is undefined as you set it here:

```
const [value, setValue]=useState(/*Here empty means undefined*/);
```

Comment: The value is correct when it is in useEffect but I cannot change it like this. formatta is a value that can change instantly. I am viewing this value for editing in the textfield. It should return like the default value and I should be able to change it

Answer (score 2):

`setState` actions are asynchronous and are batched for performance gains. This is explained in the documentation of setState.

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a
> pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this
> method can potentially return the existing value.   There is no
> guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may
> be batched for performance gains.

Below code might not execute like you expected.

```
useEffect(() => {
  authService.getAddr().then(
    (response) => {
      setndata(response.data);
    },
    (error) => {
      console.log(error);
    }
  );
  ndata
    .filter((obj) => obj._id === dataidM)
    .map((data) => setValue(data.AddressTitle));
}, [dataidM, ndata]);
```

You are making an asynchronous request and updating the `value` without waiting for the response itself. I just modified your code like below. Test and let me know if you find any issues.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const api = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await authService.getAddr();
      setndata(response?.data);
      response.data
        ?.filter((obj) => obj._id === dataidM)
        .map((data) => setValue(data.AddressTitle));
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
  api();
}, [dataidM, ndata]);
```

As @Mihail Vratchanski suggested, it's always good to initialize state values with a default value.

Comment: only when i write like this : "AddressTitle: value" is null ,  As @Mihail Vratchanski, it looks correct when I take it, but it doesn't change it because I show it as formdata.AddressTitle in the textfield.It should return like the default value and I should be able to change it